# Multiple deployment pipes on bitbucket

Tags: azure, yaml, bitbucket-pipelines, cicd

I have a solution where reside a web application and an azure function.
So different pipes should be used for deployment:

```
microsoft/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.0.3 - for web app
microsoft/azure-functions-deploy:1.0.2 - for azure function
```

How they should be combined in a *yml* file? Or do I need to have separate *yml* files?
It looks like I can't have multiple deployment steps for a single environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bitbucket Pipelines does not support multiple files for defining the pipeline nor different deployment steps for the same deployment stage so: yes, same file, same step.

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        deployment: production
        script:
          - pipe: [docker://]microsoft/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.0.3
            variables:
              FOO: bar
          - pipe: [docker://]microsoft/azure-functions-deploy:1.0.2
            variables:
              BAR: foo
```

So, deploying to "production" will deploy both the webapp and the function.

---

The docker:// prefix for the pipe is necessary if the pipes aren't registered as such but are arbitrary docker images with smart entrypoints.

---

Yet, you could use custom deployment environments like "Production Webapp" and "Production Function" so you could deploy them separatedly like

```
pipelines:
  default:
    - parallel:
      - step:
          deployment: production-webapp
          script:
            - pipe: [docker://]microsoft/azure-web-apps-deploy:1.0.3
              variables:
                FOO: bar
      - step:
          deployment: production-function
          script:
            - pipe: [docker://]microsoft/azure-functions-deploy:1.0.2
              variables:
                BAR: foo
```

and Bitbucket will keep track of the deployments made to each "environment" and also let you redeploy to them individually.