# Setting deployment in bitbucket-pipeline.yml on a higher level than step

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I want to set the deployment to use for a set of steps.  All the [documentation](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/set-up-and-monitor-bitbucket-deployments/) only shows setting deployment in a bitbucket-pipelines.yml step.

```
- step:
        name: Deploy to test
        image: aneitayang/aws-cli:1.0
        deployment: testbed
        script:
          - python deploy.py test
```

You can't have more than 1 step indicate the same deployment.

Is there a way to have multiple steps use the same deployment value?

Can I set it on the pipeline level or on the branch level?

```
pipeline:
 deployment: dev
```

OR

```
branches:  
  feature/*:  
    deployment: dev
```

OR

Is it a strict 1-1 relationship of 1 step === 1 deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a strict 1-1 relationship of 1 step === 1 deployment.

You should think of the deployment step as the minimal instructions that will move the application, as produced by the sources in the git reference where the pipeline is run, to the deployment environment.

Those instructions should be able to be repeatedly run in order redeploy the latest version, potentially restarting services and whatnot, or deploy past versions. This way Bitbucket can keep track of the PRs and commits added or subtracted on each deployment and the deployment history for each environment.

Ideally the deployment step will not include any building process. Applications would be built in previous non-deployment steps and their built artifacts would be stored anywhere. Then the deployment step would solely consist of some instructions or pipes pushing the artifacts for that pipeline run to deployment systems, retagging docker images, restarting docker services, invalidating CDN distributions, etc.

If you are working on a monorepository, which could motivate the need for multiple deployment steps for each subproject, you must either

- deploy all subprojects simultaneously in a single step
- define a different custom deployment environment for each subproject

E.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73041318/11715259

It is better to detach the deployment workflow from the runtimes of your applications. A single Bash/Python/Ansible script should be able to deploy all services, even if you are developing Ruby, C++, JS and Java. Avoid including the deployment toolchain in your applications. E.g avoid using https://www.npmjs.com/package/s3-deploy or anything similar. Pipes are very convenient for this purpose.